# Heroku , ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `tags' for #<Post:0x000000041424a0>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, error-handling, tags, undefined

So I'm not sure what it is.
On local host all works fine.

I have got this error in Heroku.

```
Started GET "/posts/new" for 79.111.231.233 at 2012-10-05 08:04:17 -0700
app/views/posts/new.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_posts_new_html_erb__735551054742361459_22419140'
app/views/shared/_post_form.html.erb:22:in `block in _app_views_shared__post_form_html_erb__2081576675630015699_18673940'
22:     <%= f.text_field :tags %>
app/views/shared/_post_form.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_shared__post_form_html_erb__2081576675630015699_18673940'
25:   <div class="actions">
21:   <div class="">
cache: [GET /posts/new] miss
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `tags' for #<Post:0x000000041424a0>):
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:19:in `new'
```

Thats what I have:

**1. Viewer**

```
<%= form_for @post  do |f| %>
```

...
    <%= f.text_field :tags %>
...

**2. Controller**

```
  def new
    @page_title = 'New post'
    @user = current_user 
    @post = Post.new
      render 'new'
  end
```

**3. Model**

```
attr_accessible :entry, :title, :private, :tags
```

**4. Schema**

```
  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
   t.string   "title",                          :null => false
   t.text     "entry",                          :null => false
   t.integer  "user_id"
   t.integer  "category_id"
   t.boolean  "private",     :default => false
   t.datetime "created_at",                     :null => false
   t.datetime "updated_at",                     :null => false
   t.string   "tags"
 end
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Did you forget to `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

You may also need to `heroku restart` if your application is already running and has cached the old data model.

Comment: The restart thing, helpful!

Comment: Life saver! All in the details!

Comment: Hallelujah.  Thank you.